# what is the necessity of c++ static cast

Tags: c++, casting

I have seen some good posts explaining in depth about various c++ cast. One of them is

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

What I'm curious about is when static cast is unavoidable? What are the things impossible to do without using static_cast operator?

Comment: Dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast are working on pointers/references, so if you want to cast a nonpointer/reference types (e.g: float to double) you can only use static cast.

Comment: CRTPs won't work without `static_cast<>` for example.

Comment: You can use reinterpret_cast for CRTP... even if it's a bad idea, the question was what is impossible to do without static_cast.

Comment: You can do anything with C-old style cast; what you can't do is knowing at compile-time wether you are doing something bad

Comment: C style cast is a superset of static cast. Any cast which compile with static cast will compile with C style cast. Which means static cast cannot be called "unavoidable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to use a `static_cast<>` over a `dynamic_cast<>` is performance. With the `dynamic_cast<>`, you get code that actually checks the dynamic type of the object, adjusting the pointer as appropriate; a `static_cast<>` always compiles to a single addition instruction at most. And since the dynamic type check may get expensive, `static_cast<>` can be orders of magnitude faster than the corresponding `dynamic_cast<>`.

Apart from this performance consideration, `static_cast<>` is not strictly needed, you can do anything it does with `dynamic_cast<>` or C-style casts.

Comment: My last three words were "or C-style casts". There is no conversion that you cannot do via a C-style cast, which is precisely why people avoid them. But they are available, and their scope encompasses the entire realm of `static_cast<>`. So, `static_cast<>` is not strictly necessary. Neither is `const_cast<>`, nor `reinterpret_cast<>`, both for the same reason. Only the `dynamic_cast<>` does something that a C-style cast can't do.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite examples is casting of enums.

```
namespace example
{
    enum rate
    {
    GOOD,
    BAD,
    UNDEFINED
    };
    enum checkstate
    {
    CHECKED,
    UNCHECKED,
    UNDEFINED
    };
}
```

if you have a function accepting example::checkstate  and you want to pass example::rate, then the best way is to use static_cast. This is also the case of casting integer values to enum values.

Comment: Is enum to other enum conversion possible by some other cast?

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, there's nothing a `static_cast` can do that a C-style cast or function-style cast can't do.  The main advantage of a `static_cast` is readability; they really jump out on the screen so you can see that a cast is taking place.